# How to remove the integer behind the name if there is any? (google sheet)

Tags: google-sheets, trim

[image]

Hi everyone,

My goal is to remove the integer behind the name (if exist) as shown in the screenshot above. Is there any trick to do this other than doing it manually? It is challenging for me because the name list is not consistent as some of the names does not have integer behind. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A3:A,"\d+$",""))
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- If you want to use `TRIM` for the value, how about `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A3:A,"\d+$","")))`?

#### Reference:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245/regexreplace)

### Added:

From OP's following replying,

> Hi Tanaike, thanks for your input. I tested both formula. It works most of the time with the exception of `Derrick Tan 1`. Beside that, is it possible to remove the `-` as well if exist? I edited my question with new screenshot example, thank you.

In this case, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A3:A,"[-\s\d]+$","")))
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for your input. I tested both formula. It works most of the time with the exception of `Derrick Tan 1`. Beside that, is it possible to remove the `-` as well if exist? I edited my question with new screenshot example, thank you.

Comment: @weizer Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. For your additional question, I added one more sample formula. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize. By the way, in my sample formula, `Derrick Tan 1` returns `Derrick Tan`. I apologize for this.